# Custom Permalinks Structure with particular word

Tags: permalinks

I have some headache trying to customizing my permalinks...

So here is what I need :
1) "mysite.com/news/" has to display all the posts.
2) "mysite.com/news/firstcat/" has to display all the posts of the "firstcat" category.
3) "mysite.com/news/firstcat/myposttitle" has to display the single post "myposttitle", which is in the "firstcat" category.

So here's what I've done :

- I have a page called "News", with "news" as slug. In the settings, I've set this page to be the blog page. So When I go to "mysite.com/news/", I have the listing of all my posts.
- In the "Permalinks" settings page, I have changed "category prefix" to "news". Now if I go to "mysite.com/news/firstcat/", I have the listing of all the posts that belong to the "firstcat" category.
- In the "Permalinks" settings page, I have changed the settings to "custom permalinks" and type "%category/%postname%". Now the permalink of my single post is "mysite.com/firstcat/myposttitle" but I want it to be "mysite.com/news/firstcat/myposttitle"... with "news" ...

How could I do that ?

Thanks !

Answer (score -2):

You Can Try This In The Custom Structure

/news/%category%/%postname%